# Updating a google maps gui

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, updates, geometry, google-polyline

After the initial `onCreate` method in Android, are there any other methods to update or change the original content in the onCreate method.

For example I initiate a GoogleMap in the `onCreate` method, with polylines and circles drawn over it. Is there a way to update this map so the old polylines and circles are removed and replaced by new ones?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `map.clear()` which removes all markers, polylines etc. and leaves a plain map. Now you can add some new stuff.

If you wanna remove just specific map objects like a polyline hold a reference and call remove.

Comment: ok but how do i do that after the oncreate method? so say i wanted to do it 20 seconds after i first initialized the map what could i use to change it?

Comment: Depends on what you wanna achieve. Remove on button click, redrawn Activity, on a special event...

Comment: i would like it to update automatically every 20 seconds with a new set of longitude and latitude values to be plotted

Comment: any ideas on refreshing the google map? with new drawings on it?